# Why doesn't the backend see its cookies when the frontend (Nuxt; SSR) makes a request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nuxt.js, ruby-on-rails-7

The Rails API application creates cookies in the sign in and refresh endpoints.

```rb
cookies.encrypted['app.refresh_token.local_user'] = {
  value: refresh_token,
  path: '/auth',
  expires: 15.days.from_now,
  secure: Rails.env.production?,
  httponly: true
}
```

When I test requests in Insomnia everything works well. I see these httpOnly cookies in Insomnia, then the backend sees them.

This is not the case with the Nuxt (SSR) application. The backend code hasn't changed, so the backend still creates httpOnly cookies for the refresh token. But when Nuxt makes a request for a refresh endpoint, then Rails shows the cookies from Nuxt, and all the values that were created by it disappear.

For this reason, I do not understand how I can store the refresh token in the httpOnly cookie on the backend side. I see that this is the only correct way to store this token, but I can't do it in any way. Now I am writing my solution from scratch, before that I tried Nuxt auth library. The problem is the same in both cases.